# Calculate range and altitude of the Google Earth KML LookAt element to fit all features (polygons)

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

I have several polygons drawn on the surface in google earth plugin. I generate a KML from them.

Question is how can I calculate parameters for the LookAt so that the view includes all the polygons when open in the desktop Google Earth?
For lat and lon it's quite simple - just calculate the center of bounding box, but what about altitude and range parameters?

For example we have two polygons:

```
1:
    40.724536 -74.001914
    40.724102 -74.001091
    40.723003 -74.002067
    40.723392 -74.002891
2:
    40.723186 -74.003112
    40.722843 -74.002311
    40.721977 -74.003036
    40.722320 -74.003738
```

Then lon and lat will be
lon=(40.724536+40.721977)/2=40.7232565
lat=-(74.001091+74.003738)/2=-74.0024145

Now how to calculate the range and altitude?

Comment: Found the Haversine Distance Formula (http://www.autocalculator.org/Calculators/Driving-Distance-Calculator.aspx) and tried to apply it to my coordinates in excel but it gives incorrect result (too big values)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Google Earth API Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/). It augments the functionality of the Earth API providing useful helper methods which wrap up commonly needed tasks for you.

It includes a [createBoundsView() method](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsViewReference#createBoundsView%28bounds,_options%29) which will build you a `LookAt` object configured to fit a given bounding box within the viewport. Does exactly what you need I think. e.g.

```
function flyToBox(max_x, max_y, min_x, min_y) {
  var bounds = new geo.Bounds([min_y, min_x], [max_y, max_x]);
  var options = {aspectRatio : $('#map3d').width() / $('#map3d').height(), scaleRange : 2};
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(gex.view.createBoundsView(bounds, options));
}
```